# Native SQL to Query Builder in Laravel5

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have two tables on Laravel 5 and have to use Query Builder. I have already got the sql for it but i am not able to convert it to Query Builder syntax. SQL is

```
SELECT COUNT(A.cid)  FROM `A` WHERE A.cid IN (SELECT `id` FROM `B` WHERE `create_user`='$name') AND `access_time` BETWEEN '$start_data' AND '$end_data'
```

when I use

```
DB::table('A')
        ->join('B', function ($join) {
            $join->on('A.id', '=', 'B.cid');
        })
        ->get();
```

some syntax like this , it's error  so how can I turn the native SQL ｌｉｋｅ　"IN" into Query　Builder　，thanks

Comment: Usually posting the error message helps others solve the issue ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Below queries and look at result:

```
$result= DB::table('a')
            ->select(DB::raw('COUNT(a.cid) as total_cid'))
            ->join('b', 'a.cid', '=', 'b.id')
            ->where('b.create_user', $name)
            ->whereBetween('a.access_time', [$start_data, $end_data])
            ->first();
```

Or try this

```
$result= DB::table('a')
            ->join('b', 'a.cid', '=', 'b.id')
            ->where('b.create_user', $name)
            ->whereBetween('a.access_time', [$start_data, $end_data])
            ->count();
```

In your question you asked how to use `IN`, for `IN` try something like this:-

```
$result= DB::table('a')->whereIn('cid', [1,2,3,4]);
```

Comment: The second method can get a result

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax for [joins in Laravel 5.2](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#joins):

```
$result= DB::table('a')
            ->join('b', 'a.id', '=', 'b.cid')
            ->select('a.cid')
            ->where('A.cid', 'like', '%string%') //optional like
            ->get();
```